# Kinesis stream binder - HA & consumer group question

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

We're working with Kinesis, and we have a single producer (to a single stream, currently a single shard), and a single consumer application, which is in HA (2 instances at the moment).

right now we see that each instance of the consumer application receives each message. we would like to change it - that just one instance will receive each message.

The producer partitions the data according to "accountId", and we'd like each instance of the consumer to receive a subset of these account ids.

We added to the consumer app's configuration the "group" part - but it's still not helping, each message is still duplicated.

So first of all - is it possible? to have more consumers than shards, and still divide the data? or do we need the amount of shards to be >= the amount of consumers?
 and seconds - what are we doing wrong?

Here's the configuration:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: X
      port: X
      database: X
      parameters: retryWrites=true&w=majority
  redis:
    repositories:
      enabled: false
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: streamName
          content-type: application/json
          group: groupName
      kinesis:
        binder:
          checkpoint:
            table: dynamo-checkpoint-table
          locks:
            table: dynamo-locks-table
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Not enough info. What version of Kinesis binder do you use? Is your `group` the  same on all consumer instances?

Comment: @ArtemBilan hi, i'm using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis version 1.2.1-release. I guess i'm basically asking what happens when there are 2 consumers in a consumer group with only 1 shard?

Comment: Only one consumer will process records from that shard. Another one will idle until the first one dies.